# Rockbottom rank newbie question about the Blender UI (Blender 2.9.0, on a Mac)

Tags: interface, tools

[image]Since this is the only forum accessible to me, here's the question: The term "Edit mode" gets used a lot, but there is more than one layout (arrangement of tools available) for Edit Mode, for example, the initial layout, with a long column of tools running up the left side, and the vertex, edge, and face icons up next to the "Edit mode" ID, plus those same three choices spelled out at the end of the row. OR: there is a different Edit Mode Layout without those two reference clusters for choosing a target. They are absent. Gone. So if I'm in one of those layouts, how do I get to the other, and vice-versa?

Comment: You may need to show what key combinations you used and the object selected

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to the online manual [Regions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html) entry you will see that there are two pull out bars, called the *tool bar* (on the left side) and the *sidebar* (on the right side) of the 3D viewport:

[image: regions in the blender main display]

You can use hotkeys to toggle those bars so that they are visible or not. The t key will toggle the tool bar and the n key will toggle the sidebar.

Also, when the bars are not present, there is an arrow that you can drag with the mouse to pull them out:

[image: arrow for the sidebar]

You can also use the arrow to drag them closed.  (When the mouse hovers over the arrow it changes into a two-arrow cursor.)

Update: The difference between the toolbars in your update are because of what object is being edited, which you don't show, or what tool is being used.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it, Chris. I added a doctored image to my original post to clarify the problem-selective editing is possible in one state, but not the other.